# How can I conditionally transform a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have 2 columns I want to loop through, 'Volume_hedge' and 'Unit_hedge'. For each row, if the data in 'Unit_hedge' says "Thousands of Barrels per Day", I want to divide the number in "Volume_hedge" (which is in the same row as the 'Unit_hedge' that equals "Thousands of Barrels per Day") by 1000.

I've tried looping through both columns enumerated and an if statement afterwards. Like I said, I works for the first 2 rows but not for the rest.

```
df2 = DataFrame(x)
columns_to_select = ['Volume_hedge', 'Unit_hedge']
for i, row in enumerate(columns_to_select):
    if df2['Unit_hedge'].loc[i] == 'Thousands of Barrels per Day':
        new_row = df2['Volume_hedge'].loc[i] / 1000
    else:
        none
    df2['Volume_hedge'].loc[i] = new_row
print(df2[columns_to_select].loc[0:8])
```

Expected results:

```
  Volume_hedge                    Unit_hedge
0         0.03  Thousands of Barrels per Day
1        0.024  Thousands of Barrels per Day
2        0.024  Thousands of Barrels per Day
3        0.024  Thousands of Barrels per Day
4        0.024  Thousands of Barrels per Day
5        0.024  Thousands of Barrels per Day
6        0.024  Thousands of Barrels per Day
7     32850000                   (MMBtu/Bbl)
8      4404000                   (MMBtu/Bbl)
```

Actual Results:

```
 Volume_hedge                    Unit_hedge
0         0.03  Thousands of Barrels per Day
1        0.024  Thousands of Barrels per Day
2           24  Thousands of Barrels per Day
3           24  Thousands of Barrels per Day
4           24  Thousands of Barrels per Day
5           24  Thousands of Barrels per Day
6           24  Thousands of Barrels per Day
7     32850000                   (MMBtu/Bbl)
8      4404000                   (MMBtu/Bbl)
```

Comment: please format your code.

Answer (score 4):

You should use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) here:

```
import numpy as np

df2["Volume_hedge"] = np.select(
    [df2["Unit_hedge"].eq("Thousands of Barrels per Day")], 
    [df2["Volume_hedge"].div(1000)], 
    df2["Volume_hedge"]
)
```

This will divide all rows where `Unit_hedge` equals "Thousands of Barrels per Day" by 1000, and leave all the other rows the same.

This also has the advantage of not being done iteratively, which is faster when using `pandas` and `numpy`

Answer (score 0):

Columns to select is a two element list. When you enumerate it, i will vary from 0 to 1. This will only apply the function to the first two rows.

If you want to iterate through the rows, you should instead use the iterrows function. Do something like,

```
for i, row in df2.iterrows():
    if row['Unit_hedge'] == 'Thousands of Barrels per Day':
        new_row = row['Volume_hedge'] / 1000
    df2['Volume_hedge'].iloc[i] = new_row
```

However, using apply rather than looping through each row is a better bet because iterating is very slow. Also setting column values while iterating through a dataframe is not preferred

Answer (score 0):

```
df['volume_hedge'][df['Unit_hedge'] == 'Thousands of Barrels per Day'] = 
df['volume_hedge'][df['Unit_hedge'] == 'Thousands of Barrels per Day']/1000
```